# Communication between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, communication

my application has 2 directives :

1. Signup
2. CreateItem

I want to call Signup from CreateItem if the user is not authenticated
but I don't know how to call Signup Directive method from CreateItem Directive method.

This is my code :

```
.directive('createitem', function($modal, $http, Global) {
return {
restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
templateUrl : 'views/item/create.html',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.openCreateItemModal = function() {
    // I want to call openSignupModal if user not authenticated (Global.authenticated)
    }
}}}
.directive('signup', function($modal, $http) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
transclude: true,
templateUrl : 'views/signup/create.html',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {   
scope.openSignupModal = function() {

}

}}};
```

This is my view  (I want to inject join directive into createitem directive)

```
<createitem join>
```

What is the cleanest way to to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple service factory that contains both methods and inject the factory anywhere you need it in the app

```
app.factory('MyModals', function() {
  return {
    openCreateItemModal: function(arg1, arg2) {

    },
    openSignupModal: function(arg1, arg2) {

    }
  }

});

.directive('createitem', function($modal, $http, Global, MyModals) {
    return {     
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        if(! scope.isAuthenticated )
        MyModals.openCreateItemModal(arg1, arg2);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. Clear answer. Now I've got one more question. What if i want to change the scope when I open the CreateItemModal. I mean, i've got a lot of business logic when initializing and when clicking buttons inside the modal. What do you suggest? Thanks. Before, when I used only a directive for modal and business logic, i attached a controller inside the directive passing scope in parameter.